OpenApi generated interface method has return type as Object (Spring Boot 3)
I've defined an API to register a User. I want to return SaveUserResponse after registeration of user is successful. However, the interface generated after gradle build has return type as Object.
Here is the userapi.yaml
paths:
  /signup:
    post:
      description: User registration API
      operationId: signup
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/SignupRequest'

      responses:
        '201':
          description: CREATED
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#components/schemas/SaveUserResponse'


components:
  schemas:
    SignupRequest:
      type: object
      description: User model for GetARoom
      required:
        - firstName
        - lastName
        - email
        - password
      properties:
        firstName:
          type: string
          description: First name of the user
          minLength: 2
          maxLength: 15

        lastName:
          type: string
          description: Last name of the user
          minLength: 1
          maxLength: 15

        email:
          type: string
          description: User's email address.

        password:
          type: string
          format: password
          description: Password of the user
          pattern: /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,12}$/
          minLength: 8
          maxLength: 12
    
    SaveUserResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        accountNumber:
          type: integer
        userId:
          type: string

The following interface got generated after the build. If you notice (Line 55), the return type of signup is ResponseEntity<Object> but I want to return ResponseEntity <SaveUserResponse> . What am I missing?

My build.gradle :
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id 'org.openapi.generator' version '6.6.0'
}

group = 'com.ums'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs("$buildDir/generated/openapi/src/main/java")
        }
    }
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "spring"
    inputSpec.set("$projectDir/src/main/resources/api/userapi.yaml")
    outputDir.set("$buildDir/generated/openapi")
    apiPackage.set("com.ums.userservice.api")
    modelPackage.set("com.ums.userservice.model")
    configOptions = [
            library : "spring-boot",
            useSpringBoot3: "true"
    ]

    additionalProperties = [
            dateLibrary: "java8",
            generateModels: true,
            generateApis: true,
            interfaceOnly: true,
            skipDefaultInterface: true,
            useBeanValidation: true,
            serializableModel: true
    ]
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation group: 'org.openapitools', name: 'jackson-databind-nullable', version: '0.2.6'


    implementation group: 'io.swagger.core.v3', name: 'swagger-annotations', version: '2.2.21'
    implementation group: 'io.swagger', name: 'swagger-annotations', version: '1.6.14'

    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.24'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    dependsOn(tasks.openApiGenerate)
}


This is weird, your schema looks correct and your version is recent. Only thing unexpected to me is interfaceOnly=true, why do you use that?

no, interfaceOnly makes sense, your Api is an interface in the end.

is SaveUserResponse anywhere to be found in your generated-sources?

@julaine yes, SaveUserResponse model can be found in generated. However, intelliJ says that it isn't being used anywhere (which is true since API return type is Object for some reason).
Can you try the above configuration on your end to see if it works correctly or not?

@julaine resolved, see my answer :)

Found the issue: It was with the following line
$ref: '#components/schemas/SaveUserResponse' .
It should be '#/components/schemas/SaveUserResponse'

weird behaviour to default to 'Object' instead of failing. Glad you solved it.
